# How to obtain UTC value in zOS assembler

Tags: assembly, time, zos

I'm aware that the STCK instruction will give me a TOD value which is the time that has passed since 1-1-1900.  How can I get the UTC time that has passed since 1-1-1970?

Answer (score 1):

If your Assembler code is LE-conforming (i.e. you use the [CEEENTRY](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=macros-ceeentry-macro-generate-language-environment-conforming-prolog#clament) entry logic and its attendant macros) you can call C library functions such as [time() or time64()](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=functions-timetime64-determine-current-utc-time) to get your desired result.

If you cannot make your code LE-conforming for some reason, I suggest the [TIME macro](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=date-linkagesystem), specifying BIN format and ZONE=UTC, then calculate the offset from midnight 01-Jan-1970 by subtracting the difference between that time/date and the basis for the Time Of Day clock which is midnight 01-Jan-1900.  It's a constant, of course, so you only have to figure that out once.  I used [this calculator](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/timeduration.html) and got [2,208,988,800](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?m1=01&d1=01&y1=1900&m2=01&d2=01&y2=1970&h1=00&i1=00&s1=00&h2=00&i2=00&s2=00) as the constant.  Note that TIME BIN returns a 32 bit integer indicating number of *hundredths* of a second since the epoch.

Comment: I don't have access to the LE from my environment.

Comment: Don't forget to consider the impact of leap-seconds if you want a truly precise answer. Also, many mainframes are configured with UTC in the hardware clock, and you'll find the timezone offset in the z/OS CVT if you should need to go to/from local time.